# iOS and SQL: Restricting access

Tags: mysql, ios, sql, cocoa-touch

Bit of a broad question here. I want to host an SQL database to store user data from an iOS based app. I want to save data using the users facebook ID. Now, from the app, I want to be able to query the database but only retrieve the users fb ID and friends of the users IDs (I'll have gotten permission to share their data with friends). From inside the app, this isn't a problem as I can just only query using those IDs, but, whats to stop someone from querying my database from outside the app?

So I guess my question is, how can I restrict access of the SQL database to queries generated from the app itself rather than a simple web browser or tech savvy terminal user who has somehow gotten a hold of the link to the database? User privacy is obviously very important.

Comment: You could host a local SQLite file in the App Sandbox, then create do an asynchronous call to periodically transfer data from the SQLite .db to the remote SQL Database or Server using GCD, or some other thread running in background. You could also have the SQLite db abstracted with CoreData.

Comment: I think there was a gap in my understanding of how SQL files are hosted. Tell me if this sounds right (I just did some reading). I host the database on the server and protect it with a username and password – I store the username and password in a file on the server but outside the webspace. Then I use a PHP script in the webspace  to manage entries and queries of the database. That way I can filter queries as valid vs invalid (ie not information a given user has access to). Is that right?

Comment: This seems like more of a web based question, you might have more luck tagging it with PHP.